# Work with meta_query and default field in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would know how to add a relation `OR` or `AND` between `meta_query` field and a `default field` Using the `WP_query` class.

```
$args = [
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'job-offers',
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'region',
            'value' => $infos['region'],
            'compare' => '='
        ]
    ],
    'post_title' => $infos['title'],
];
```

Here I would have a `OR` relation between `post_title` and the `meta_query`.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

```
    $args = [
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'job-offers',
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'region',
            'value' => $infos['region'],
            'compare' => '='
        ]
    ],
    'post_title' => $infos['title'],
    'relation' => 'OR',
];
```

Adding `relation` key doesn't change anything.

Comment: You need to save the `post_title` value into the meta table in order to use `meta_query` against it.

Comment: Of course it should work, but this is totally obvious to be able to add a relation between wordpress field and custom field... I'm sure there is an easy way but nothing is working for now..

Comment: See my answer for an implementation.

Comment: Yep thank you, I can't believe WP_query doesn't allow to query on post_title or other basic field...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`meta_query` and the `relation` value only affect data that is in the `postmeta` table in the database. Therefore you can't do a meta `OR` relation query between a meta key (`region`) which is in `postmeta` and `post_title` which is in the `posts` table.

A workaround is to add a filter that mirrors the `post_title` into the `postmeta` table for use inside `meta_query`.

```
add_action( 'save_post', function( $post_id ) {
    if ( $post_id && get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'post' ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'posts_title', get_the_title( $post_id ) );
    }
});

// This is a very light implementation. Be sure to do some
// checks in order to save the meta value only when really
// needed. This implementation might save it for auto-drafts
// and such.
```

Now there should be a value inside `postmeta` table that has the key `posts_title`. Then in a `WP_Query` you can do

```
$posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'job-offers',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
         array(
             'key' => 'posts_title',
             'value' => $wanted_title_value,
             'compare' => '=='
         ),
         array(
             'key' => 'region',
             'value' => $wanted_region_value,
             'compare' => '=='
         )
    )
));
```